# How to create a iCal ics Feed in PHP 

Tags: php, mysql, icalendar

I am looking for specifics in creating an iCal feed, for use in applications such as Google Calendar and on peoples phones.

I currently have a script using the [iCalendar](http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php) class that when the url is visited, an ics file is created and sent to the browser:

```
  function returnCalendar() {
    $filename = $this->getConfig( 'filename' );
    $output   = $this->createCalendar();
    $filesize = strlen( $output );
    if( 'xcal' == $this->format )
      header( 'Content-Type: application/calendar+xml; charset=utf-8' );
    else
      header( 'Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8' );
    header( 'Content-Length: '.$filesize );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: max-age=10' );
    echo $output;
    die();
  }
```

I would like (as I previously mentioned) to create a feed (a unique url per user), and was wondering about the techicalities of this? I was thinking I would need a cronjob to just generate a calandar for everyone and then link users to this feed, however this seems very inefficient if say only one user is using the feed.

Would it be possible to set the script to only run when someone requested a calandar and then send them the appropriate one back?

Does anyone know how often Google Calandar etc updates, how it works and how I can test it?

Many thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the iCal calandar class for PHP, then link the users to a PHP file which does live generation (possibly with some sort of half an hour cache system to stop it being bombarded).

Using a cronjob for generation of data would be kind of heavy on the cpu usage!

Comment: Could you add a URL to what you are describing ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create `cronjob`

If you create script which takes `user_id` and some `auth_key` and after fetch all details and parse them into feed , it can work just like that

Cronjob is option in case this type of scripting would be server-side-intensive 
Then use Cronjob to create cache and public script to deploy cached data to users feed-reader

I think most of feeds are created on-query and not pre-created to cache results

You can use this library to create feed easily
http://ajaxray.com/blog/php-universal-feed-generator-supports-rss-10-rss-20-and-atom

Note.1: Don't forget that connection is most of time initiated from user-side to server-side! So most often server isn't notifying you but you're asking server for notify

Comment: That link is broken.. :(

Comment: @mmmshuddup I've repaired it :-)